# Terrans land on a planet with cat-like aliens and start going missing, two of the crew are werewolves that think it is the perfect place

Tags: story-identification, aliens, space-exploration, werewolf

I just remember a glimpse from around 40 years ago. The story may be older.

An exploration space ship from Terra is landing on an alien planet. The Earthlings are coming in contact with the alien cat-like inhabitants. The natives seem to be peaceful. But some crew men are vanishing and no one knows why.

Just two mechanics know more. They have seen the alien creatures turning wild at night and killing the Terrans.  But they have no fear. In contrary they are happy. They think that they have found the perfect place.

They are werewolves, the born superior enemies of cats in search for a place for their race. They are hungry for fight and heating up the hostility by clandestine killing the cat people.

Comment: Was this a short story, novella, novel?

Comment: I don't know. I guess I was just reading the abstract, the advertising for or a snippet of a coming booklet

Comment: The [Catteni series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catteni_Series) seems to partially match but it's not close enough of a match for me to post it as an answer. It's also probably too new but was developed from the 1970 short story "The Thorns of Barevi".

Comment: There are several points of similarity to the 1984 A. Bertram Chandler novel *Frontier of the Dark* but...will you be able to tell if an answer is correct, since you apparently haven't actually read the work?

Comment: It depends if you can describe the scene where the two werewolves observe the cat people